# Using R to Grab Multiple Quandl Future Curves

Tags: r

I am trying to grab settlement values from 12 different future curves on Quandl and then assign them into an xts object. I am currently getting the error

> "Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

and only one column. Ideally I want to have twelve columns named CL1, CL2, etc.

```
for (i in 1:12) {
  data1 = Quandl(paste("CHRIS/CME_CL", i, sep = ""), start_date= "2017-01-01", type = "xts")
  if (i == 1){ CL <- cbind(data1$Date, data1$Settle) }
  if(i > 1){CL = cbind(CL, data$Settle)}
}
```

Comment: Your for loop doesn't do anything. All you do is create the same type of object over and over (12 times over) .  You need to initalize it as I've done in it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
data1 = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 279))
for (i in 1:12){
  data1[,i] = Quandl(paste("CHRIS/CME_CL",i, sep=""), start_date="2017-01-01")$Settle
}
```

Can you verify if this works? If it works, you should be able to convert the `data.frame()` object to a series one.

I got this error after working on it a bit.

> Error: { "quandl_error": { "code": "QELx01", "message": "You have
>   exceeded the anonymous user limit of 50 calls per day. To make more
>   calls today, please register for a free Quandl account and then
>   include your API key with your requests." } }

Hope it works.

Comment: It works, but just drops the dates off. That is why I was trying to make it use XTS. Thank you though as it leads to a solution that works for me.